# How to filter Balance Sheet report by unassigned tracking options in Xero API?

Tags: xero-api

In the Xero Dashboard UI, we can filter Balance Sheet report by selecting "Unassigned" for the tracking option to get all the entries without any tracking option. How can we do the same in the API or SDK?

I have tried setting `trackingOptionID1` parameter to `null`, `"false"`, `0`, empty string, non-existent GUID but it just ignores this parameter and returns all the entries.